# Configuring a duplex connector for linking with Apollo Broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I have an Apollo broker configured as a stomp server. Now I want to configure an ActiveMQ broker which links to the Apollo broker and enable message propagation in both directions.
That is, I want the Apollo broker and ActiveMQ broker to work both as consumers and producers.

Will this networkconnector configuration at ActiveMQ broker meet my requirement?

```
    <networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector name="linkToApolloBroker"
       uri="static:(stomp://apollo_broker_ip:61000)"
       networkTTL="3"
       duplex="true" />
    </networkConnectors>
    <persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/dynamic-broker1/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    ...

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Actually, I need the Apollo to provide services for the web while passing messages to and fro to ActiveMQ broker. If I have 2 brokers talking with each other, their local clients can have direct access to the locally persisted queues and to an extend remain immune to network fluctuations.

Answer (score 2):

There is interoperability in the Network of brokers configuration between ActiveMQ and Apollo.  You might be able to configure a bridge between the two using the JMS Bridge feature of ActiveMQ since Apollo does support openwire.  The configuration you have won't work.

Have a look at the [JMS to JMS bridge](http://activemq.apache.org/jms-to-jms-bridge.html) documentation.

[Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is also a potential solution to your problem.  You can probably create a Camel route that does what you want.